# Services down after implementing High Availability on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, high-availability

After trying to implement High Availability to one of the existing servers following this article
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/

After I was done the newly created machine is running, however I cannot RDP or PING any of the services that are running on the server existing. It shows that the VM is running

Has anyone faced such a problem before ?

Answer (score 0):

In case this unexpected issue happens. The workaround is to create an XSmall VM and RDP to the VM that is not responding through internal IP. This should get it to start.